# The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I want to execute this command:

```
kubectl apply -f namespace.yaml
```

I had this error message:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Some answers have been posted in Stackoverflow like using `kubectl` with:

```
--kubeconfig=~/.kube/config
```

But this didn't solve my problem.

This is my `namespace.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my_namespace
```

I'm using GKE (1.10.6-gke.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure kubectl to use your cluster as described here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart